# One-to-Many relation not saving prisma

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have the following models:

```
model Company {
  id            String         @id @default(uuid())
  name          String
  email         String
  cocNumber     String
  taxNumber     String?
  moneybirdId   String?        @unique
  addresses     Address[]
  employees     Person[]
  subscriptions Subscription[]
  orders        Order[]
}
model Address {
  id           String    @id @default(uuid())
  moneybirdId  String    @unique
  primary      Boolean
  street       String
  houseNumber  Int?
  locationName String
  extension    String?
  zipCode      String
  city         String
  country      Country   @relation(fields: [countryId], references: [id])
  countryId    String
  companies    Company[]
  persons      Person[]
}

model Country {
  id      String    @id @default(uuid())
  name    String
  isoCode String
  adresses Address[]
}
```

And the following query:

```
let companyInput = {
                    cocNumber: newCompany.chamber_of_commerce,
                    email: newCompany.email,
                    name: newCompany.company_name,
                    taxNumber: newCompany.tax_number,
                    moneybirdId: newCompany.id,
                    addresses: {
                        connectOrCreate: [
                            {
                                create: {
                                    city: newCompany.city,
                                    extension: extension,
                                    houseNumber: parseInt(housenumber),
                                    locationName: "",
                                    primary: true,
                                    zipCode: newCompany.zipcode,
                                    street: street,
                                    country: {connect: {id: country.id}},
                                    moneybirdId: newCompany.id,
                                },
                                where: {
                                    moneybirdId: newCompany.id
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

Resulting in :     cause: "No 'Country' record(s) (needed to inline the relation on 'Address' record(s)) was found for a nested connect on one-to-many relation 'AddressToCountry'."

country.id is present and correct.

The issue shouldn't exist for a one-to-many in my experience, this looks like a many-to-many error. Is this a bug?

Worth mentioning: Create in stead of connectOrCreate with the same connect function works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, .next caching on the api route was retrieving old ID's for the countries. Deleted .next folder and recompiled, added no cache